# Assign ExecuteReader to Array

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to assign a `PagedDataSource` to `ExecuteReader()` but I get the error saying it needs to be `ICollection`.

I want all the data it returns as it is going to be assigned in a repeater. At first i just assigned the repeater to the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` and it worked ok, now they want paging and I'm not sure how to alter the query to produce an Array.

```
conn.Open();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("[safetyGuidanceSearch]", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iwc", inwardCode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owc", outwardCode);

var objPds = new PagedDataSource();
objPds.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();// turn into an array
```

What should I be trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the array first.

```
var result = new List<whatevertypespreturns>();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read()){
    result.add(reader.GetXxxx(0);
}
objPds.DataSource = result.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    SqlDataReader dr;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();

    var cmd = new SqlCommand("[safetyGuidanceSearch]", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iwc", inwardCode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owc", outwardCode);

    var objPds = new PagedDataSource();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();// turn into an array
    dt.load(dr);
```

now you can do what you want with your datatable just call it like bellow

```cs
    objPds.DataSource = dt;
```